# Reference existing scss assets after installing `cssbundling-rails` on existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6, sprockets

After installing the `cssbundling-rails` [gem](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails) I'm having trouble referencing my existing `.scss` files that live under `app/assets/stylesheets/`.

When you install the `cssbundling-rails` gem it:

1. removes your `application.css` (https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/blob/main/lib/install/install.rb#L13) which contains all the references ( `*= require_tree .` `*= require_self`) to then be used in the asset pipeline.
2. Replaces it with `application.tailwind.css` (I ran the tailwind install)
3. Creates a new folder called `builds` that contains `application.css` with all tailwind css I use.

The result of 3 is then used <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %> tag in the application layout as normal.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new rails `Rails 6.1.4.1` app
2. `rails g scaffold post`
3. add some styles in `post.scss` and verify styles are applied
4. install `cssbundling-rails`
5. Install tailwind option
6. restart server using `./bin/dev` and you'll see the styles not getting picked up.

A couple things I've tried.

- Referencing the stylesheet directly in `assets/config/manifest.js`
- Adding an import rule in the `application.tailwind.css` to reference existing `scss` files.
- Adding the css directly to `application.tailwind.css` file. **This does work** and the styles are correctly applied. I'm sure this is not the intended pattern.

Where and how can I reference exiting `.scss` under `app/assets/stylesheets` to be used in the new bundling/build process?

Admittedly, I think this stems from not fully understanding sprockets, asset pipeline, and bundling/build processes. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on @computer_smile's answer.

`*= require posts` is a [Sprockets directive](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives).

So what's happening here is:

When [css-bundling](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails) is installed, the command `./bin/dev` will start a [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) process, based on what you've setup in your local `Procfile.dev`.

Per default, that includes a line like `css: yarn build:css --watch`.

The `yarn build:css` command is setup in your `package.json` file.

When you have css-bundling setup to use tailwind, that yarn build:css will run `tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css`

The Sprockets directive `= require posts` will be ignored by yarn. (It is treated like a css comment.)

At this point, you can check that your build (which yarn produced) in `assets/builds/application.css` has all your tailwind styles, and your Sprockets directive (in form of a css comment) `= require posts`.

Only now, when you are using Sprockets, will this directive be turned into actual css, when you start your rails server (which you should be able to confirm in your browser).

Answer (score 0):

For now in `application.tailwind.css` I'm using the standard require to include these styles. This is currently working as expected in dev environment.

```
/*
 *= require posts
 @tailwind base;
 @tailwind components;
 @tailwind utilities;
*/
```